The F-test and the t-test reject the null hypothesis while the KS test and the Chi-Squared test do not
This is a follow-up question to How can the F-test reject the null hypothesis while the KS test does not?.
Let's consider I perform the following tests:

Two-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test (KS-test),
Two-sample chi-squared test (CS-test),
Two-sample t-test (T-test),
Two-sample F-test (F-test).

For different couples of samples, I get the following 3 scenarios related to the rejection or not of the null hypothesis, H (H = 0 means that it fails to reject the null hypothesis, while H = 1 means that it rejects the null hypothesis):

Case A: H(KS-test) = 0, H(CS-test) = 0, H(T-test) = 0, H(F-test) = 0
Case B: H(KS-test) = 0, H(CS-test) = 0, H(T-test) = 0, H(F-test) = 1
Case C: H(KS-test) = 0, H(CS-test) = 0, H(T-test) = 1, H(F-test) = 1

In all the scenarios, for both KS-test and CS-test, we fail to reject the null hypothesis. In particular, for Case A, we fail to reject the null hypothesis for all the tests here considered. However, for Cases B and C, we reject the null hypothesis of, respectively, the F-test only, and of both the F-test and T-test.
Then, can we still say that the "two data samples come from the same distribution" (when KS-test and CS-test fail to reject the null hypothesis), if either we reject the null hypothesis of the F-test only (i.e. H(F-test) = 1), or if we reject the null hypothesis of both the F-test and T-test (i.e. H(F-test) = 1 and H(t-test) = 1)?

These tests are sensitive to different aspects of the probability distribution and make different assumptions about the underlying process. Likely, one of the tests is more justifiable than the others.

Thanks @FransRodenburg.. Which test would be more justifiable than the others?

That depends on what it is you're actually comparing.

Part1 1. OK, well, I am just comparing the 4 tests mentioned in my question. Nothing more or different. According to the answer given by @Acccumulation in the "How can the F-test reject the null hypothesis while the KS test does not?" question, to me it looks like that the KS-test is "more important" than the F-test and the T-test, since the KS-test tests many different attributes, while the F-test assesses the variance only, and the T-test evaluates the mean mainly.

Part 2. With this in mind, if only the F-test rejects (Case B),  I would conclude saying that the "two data samples come from a very similar distribution" (since H(KS-test)=0 and H(CS-test)=0), where the main difference lies in the variance (since H(F-test)=1). However, if both H(F-test)=1 and H(t-test)=1, I do not really know what to think, according to the graphical representation of @Acccumulation in the "How can the F-test reject the null hypothesis while the KS test does not?" question.

The lack of rejection by those tests is not a confirmation of their null hypotheses. What the lack of rejection means is that there is insufficient evidence for that particular test to refute the null hypothesis, not sufficient evidence to accept the null hypothesis.
With that in mind, I see no logical inconsistencies when four expeditions go out looking for something and only two come back having found it.

Thanks @Dave for your answer!
With the "lack of rejection", do you mean "fail to reject", i.e. $H=0$? If yes, I understand that the "fail of rejection" is not a confirmation of their null hypotheses... which makes me confused since I knew that when H=0, i.e. when we do not reject the null hypotheses, the null hypotheses would be confirmed... So, does it mean that when $H=0$ there "insufficient evidence for that particular test to refute the null hypothesis"? Then, why should we perform these tests?

@Ommo What do you mean that $H = 0$?

with $H=0$ I mean that the test fails to reject the null hypothesis, while with $H=1$ I mean that we reject the null hypothesis....

Yes, you are in the $H=0$ situation where you fail to reject the null hypothesis. That is not the same as accepting the null hypothesis.

Ah ok, thanks for letting me know :-)

In your statement "when four expeditions go out looking for something and only two come back having found it.", with "only two come back having found it", do you refer to the F-test and to the T-test, right?

The expeditions that comes back having found something are the two that are able to reject, yes, in this analogy.

Thanks a lot, your analogy is clear now :-)
